# How are functions objects but not name/value pairs?

Tags: javascript, function, object

As I'm learning javascript, I understand objects to be a collection of name/value pairs. For example, taken directly from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

`An object is a collection of properties, and a property is an association between a name and a value.`

And I know that functions are also objects. For example, I can do:

```
function myFunc() { return "I'm a function"; }
myFunc.name = "Bob";
```

and

```
myFunc.name
```

will print "Bob".

However,

```
myFunc
```

will print

```
function myFunc() { return "I'm a function"; }
```

which isn't a name/value pair; it's a function.

Whereas if I did something like:

```
var myObj = { prop1: "hello", prop2: "world" }

myObj
```

will print

```
Object {prop1: "hello", prop2: "world"}
```

So I'm a bit confused how to reconcile that functions are objects and objects are collections of name/value pairs, yet functions aren't collections of name/value pairs.

Comment: Remember that objects have a `.toString()` property that governs how the object is rendered as a string. Remember also that the developer console can do whatever it wants to. Functions are in fact real objects. The nature of an object does not depend on what it looks like when converted to a string or dumped to the console.

Comment: But even disregarding the way that it is displayed in the console. I still don't understand "functions are objects and objects are collections of name/value pairs". I don't see how function -> name/value pair.

Comment: @mattm `var foo = function() {}; foo.keyName = "value";` This causes `foo` to have a property with a name/value. You can add as many properties as you like, creating a collection of name/value pairs.

Comment: Functions are objects, but they're also functions; they have an intrinsic nature beyond that of their simple "objectness".  If you add properties to a function as if it were a plain object, and then (for example) pass it to a function that iterates through the properties and displays their values, the function object will seem perfectly normal. In addition to its "objectness", of course, the function can be invoked as a function.

Comment: @Pointy: "Functions are objects, but they're also functions; they have an intrinsic nature beyond that of their simple 'objectness'" That clears it up a lot.

Comment: @mattm oh good. Understand that I know where your head-scratching comes from; the nature of the language in this respect *is* a little weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's a good question to ask. The demarcation between function and object may seem as a fuzzy concept in it's core, but I would simply not recommend to think about a function as an object using the definition "object is a collection of keys and values".

You can check [W3C objects article](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Objects_in_JavaScript) and (especially) [W3C function article](http://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_functions)
to see that a function is never actually called and object.

I think the case of a function shows pretty good that an object can be perceived as more than simply "a collection of properties, and a property is an association between a name and a value", but in practice it often is.

A definition I'd propose for function regarding it's object nature:

**Function shares all of a regular object's features, but is an extraordinary object in a fact that it can react to "()" operator, that evaluates the function's inner logic.**